Unable to get JWT decoded token in PHP Slim 4 middleware
I'm developping an API with PHP Slim 4 with JWT authentication. I want to log every request in AWS CloudWatch.
It works, but I want to add in AWS CloudWatch a part of JWT decoded token.
I use tuupola/slim-jwt-auth for JWT auth and I added 'before' function for returning $request with decoded_token_data attribute.
But when I process the request, I can't get decoded_token_data attribute.
It's strange because in my APIs I'm able to get the decoded_token_data attribute
Here's my full example code:
index.php
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/Handler/AwsCloudWatchHandler.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/Middleware/CloudWatchMiddleware.php';

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Monolog\Logger;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use DI\Container;
use Aws\CloudWatchLogs\CloudWatchLogsClient;
use Tuupola\Middleware\JwtAuthentication;
use App\Middleware\CloudWatchMiddleware;
use App\Handler\AwsCloudWatchHandler;

$container = new Container();
AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$app = AppFactory::create();
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();
$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

// JWT Configuration
$container->set('jwt', function() {
    return [
        'secret' => 'jwt_secret'
    ];
});

// Middleware CORS personnalisé
$corsMiddleware = function (Request $request, $handler) {
    $response = $handler->handle($request);
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:63342')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin, Authorization')
        ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS');
};

$app->add($corsMiddleware);

// JWT Middleware
$app->add(new JwtAuthentication([
    "secret" => $container->get('jwt')['secret'],
    "attribute" => "decoded_token_data",
    "secure" => false,
    "algorithm" => ["HS256"],
    "path" => ["/"], // Protect all routes except specified
    "ignore" => ["/login"], // Ignore the login route
    "before" => function ($request, $arguments) {
        $request = $request->withAttribute("decoded_token_data", $arguments["decoded"]);
        echo json_encode($request->getAttributes()); // For debug : I get decoded JWT
        return $request;
    },
    "error" => function ($response, $arguments) {
        $data = [];
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];

        $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data));
        return $response->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
]));

// AWS CloudWatch Configuration
$container->set('cloudwatch', function() {
    return new CloudWatchLogsClient([
        'region'  => 'eu-west-3',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'xxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        ]
    ]);
});

// Logging Configuration
$container->set('logger', function($container) {
    $logger = new Logger('api-logger');
    $cloudwatch = $container->get('cloudwatch');
    $cloudWatchHandler = new AwsCloudWatchHandler($cloudwatch, 'APIXXXX', 'API Requests');
    $logger->pushHandler($cloudWatchHandler);
    return $logger;
});

// Middleware for AWS CloudWatch logging - comment for disable logging to aws
$app->add(new CloudWatchMiddleware($container->get('logger')));

require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes/login.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes/users.php';
require __DIR__ . '/../src/routes/tasks.php';

$app->run();

CloudWatchMiddleware.php
<?php
namespace App\Middleware;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Psr\Http\Server\RequestHandlerInterface;
use Psr\Http\Server\MiddlewareInterface;
use Monolog\Logger;

class CloudWatchMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(Logger $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function process(Request $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface {
        $start = microtime(true);

        // Process the request
        $response = $handler->handle($request);

        $end = microtime(true);
        $duration = $end - $start;

        $decodedToken = $request->getAttribute('decoded_token_data');

        echo json_encode($request->getAttributes()); // For debug: I get nothing

        $domain = $decodedToken['domain'] ?? 'unknown';

        $logData = [
            'method' => $request->getMethod(),
            'uri' => (string)$request->getUri(),
            'status' => $response->getStatusCode(),
            'duration' => $duration,
            'IP address' => $request->getServerParams()['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            'headers' => $request->getHeaders(),
            'body' => (string)$request->getBody(),
            'response_body' => (string)$response->getBody(),
            'domain' => $domain
        ];

        $this->logger->info('API Request', $logData);

        return $response;
    }
}

route example:
<?php
/** @var array $app */

use Slim\Routing\RouteCollectorProxy;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;

$app->group('/tasks', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
    $group->get('', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {


        // Connect to the database
        $domain = $request->getAttribute('decoded_token_data')['domain']; // It works here!
        $dbConfig = getDatabaseConfig($domain);


....

